# Help with jQuery :last selector

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like so.

```
<ul id="comment_list">
 <li><ul><li></li></ul></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

For brevity I left out the nested ul's in each li tag... I'm trying to remove the last li in the comment_list, what's happening is it is getting removed along with the last li in each nested ul. How do I stop that?

I have this:

```
$("#comment_list li:last-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$("#comment_list > li:last-child").remove();`

Comment: perfect, I spent a good amount of time debugging my app trying to figure out what was causing both li's to be removed. Is there a name for that greater than operator... where can I find out more about it, and if there are alternate ones.

Comment: @nick: The `>` is symbolic of "direct descendant" ([or child](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)) element in CSS and jQuery alike.

Comment: @Brad, so if you turned it around < would it only pick up nested elements?

Comment: @nick: Not sure what you're going for, but W3C has a good write-up on the [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching). You always want to think of it as a "top-down" pattern, which is why it's a greater than symbol. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try
    $("#comment_list > li:last-child").remove();

Answer (score 0):

':last-child' is different to ':last'

':last-child' is a group selector that will select multiple children that match the selector inside the parent. ':last' will only ever pick 'the last' element that matches the selector.

Try this code instead:

```
$("div#comment_list li:last").remove();
```

Hope that helps you bro!

W.

Comment: Please [do not include a signature or tagline](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your post(s).

Comment: thanks for explaining the two similiar but different selectors.